# jenkinsfile to autodetect the gitlab branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecs

Here is my scenario, I have two branches in gitlab, "master" and staging.

I need to consolidate the jenkinsfile such that I can use the same file for both the staging and master branch but need to execute different set of action for each branch

what I am trying to do is if a tag push is committed to staging branch jenkins will build the docker file,upload it to aws ecr and launch a new docker instance in the aws ecs staging cluster and if a tag push into master branch it will deploy it into another live cluster.

I used the "JENKINS PIPELINE" project and write the below code in jenkinsfile but the env.BRANCH_NAME is always returning the null value.

```
if  (env.BRANCH_NAME == "staging") {


      def  serviceName       = ""
      def  taskFamily        = ""
      def  clusterName       = ""
      } else if  (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {

      def  serviceName       = ""
      def  taskFamily        = ""
      def  clusterName       = ""
      }
```

when using "JENKINS MULTIBRANCH" pipeline project it scanned the project and automatically identified all the branch but it seems each branch has its own webhook.

I am really confused with the MULTIBRANCH JENKINS. Should we configure 2 different webhook in the gitlab?  one for staging and another for master? will the jenkins pull and automatically switch to the staging branch when we do a git tag push to the staging branch in the gitlab?

it looks like when we do a tag push to the staging branch in the gitlab,  jenkins is pulling the jenkinsfile from the staging branch but processing the files in the master branch.

is there any method we can use the "JENKINS PIPELINE" project instead of "MULTI BRANCH"?

Comment: Are you using `scripted` or `declarative` type pipeline. In case of `declarative` can you try adding this code snippet inside `script` block.

Comment: @SunilThorat I guess its is declarative pipeline, Can you paste the code once more as I cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on GitLab it is not `env.BRANCH_NAME`, it is `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#predefined-environment-variables

One trick I have used to validate environment variables in a Jenkinsfile is to run a shell script command to display your environment.  Such as `sh printenv` (assuming your Jenkins build agent is Linux based)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. `env.BRANCH_NAME`  was showing the correct branch name (I echoed the variable) when I use MULTIBRANCH JENKINS job but then the if condition is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "equals" function instead of "==" operator `myStringVar.equals(<someOtherValue>)`

You case will look like something:-

```
if  (env.BRANCH_NAME.equals('staging')) {
  def  serviceName       = ""
  def  taskFamily        = ""
  def  clusterName       = ""
  } else if  (env.BRANCH_NAME.equals('master')) {
  def  serviceName       = ""
  def  taskFamily        = ""
  def  clusterName       = ""
  }
```

Ans the variable `env.BRANCH_NAME` will be available in case of multibranch pipeline.